# How to monitor or profile DOM updates in Chrome or Firefox?

Tags: javascript, dom, browser, profiling, single-page-application

I have an application (built on React) that seems to be causing more overhead -- likely DOM updates -- than it should. Normally when a user enters any data, e.g. a single character, a DOM update would occur, but a denounce has been implemented so this *shouldn't* happen, though perhaps the debounce itself is problematic.

While I could devise some visual ways to diagnose this, I thought it might be useful to collect profiling data, in particular, something like a histogram or graph of DOM updates per second sounds useful.

I don't mind using either Firefox or Chrome to do the profiling, but I will note as an aside that Firefox seems to be hit even harder than Chrome by this performance issue.

Answer (score 0):

Honestly, the best browser is Microsoft Edge Dev. [Here](https://www.microsoftedgeinsider.com/en-us/download) is a link to the download page. Edge Dev a bunch of extra options, under the Settings wheel, and turn on all the extra ones that you may need. There are 3 options but like I said I suggest Dev. It has a feature (3-D View) that enables you to see all the elements on the page and how they are stack/interacting with each other, plus you can change it to DOM View if that helps. It allows you to move around and interact with the 3-D model and it will show above what it's actually doing. It is a great way to "See" your page.  You can also download Firefox Developer Edition which has Dev tools too, but not like Edge. Run your program in an Edge browser, right-click and Inspect the page, it is easier if you un-dock the console. Change the settings to fit your needs and then click the Profile Tab. You should be able to run it through there and get results. Look around in the Inspect window and the Console Tab, which will log errors and details if you choose those options, that may tell you if there is some request that is holding things up.

Comment: P.S There are extra options in Edge if you click the 3 dots in the corner of the Inspect window, one of which is a 3-D rendering of the site or the DOM, depending on which you choose.

Comment: You did not answer the question. The question was specific.